# RegEx for Consecutive Expressions with OR?

Tags: javascript, regex

How can i match a series of expressions with OR's? This is for scrubbing plain text data which may contain imbedded spaces or tabs at the front of each row. This is in preparation for a `.split` at newlines.

```
const oldStr = `abc
   abc
    abc`;
```

I want to replace:

```
newline + 0 or more spaces OR tabs
```

with

```
newline
```

This achieves what i want

```
newStr = oldStr.replaceAll(/\n */g, "\n");  // newline + spaces
newStr = newStr.replaceAll(/\n\t*/g, "\n");  // newline + tabs
```

How to do that in a single statement? The following fail:

Attempt, with pipe:

```
newStr = oldStr.replaceAll(/\n *|\t*/g, "\n");
```

Attempt, with parens around the OR:

```
newStr = oldStr.replaceAll(/\n( *|\t*)/g, "\n");
```

Attempt, with slashes around the OR:

```
newStr = oldStr.replaceAll(/\n/ *|\t*/g, "\n");
```

Attempt, with square brackets instead of pipe:

```
newStr = oldStr.replaceAll(/\n[ *\t*]/g, "\n");
```

Attempt, with quotes and pipe:

```
newStr = oldStr.replaceAll("\n *\t|*/g", "\n");
```

Attempt, with quotes and pipe and parens:

```
newStr = oldStr.replaceAll("\n( *|\t*)/g, "\n");
```

Attempt, with quotes and square brackets:

```
newStr = oldStr.replaceAll("\n[ *\t*]/g", "\n");
```

Feel free to offer a solution which combines the cleaning with a `.split` statement, or a non-regex solution.

Comment: I don't see why that wouldn't just work: `newStr = oldStr.replaceAll(/\n( *|\t*)/g, "\n");`

Comment: @Matthias That doesn't remove leading spaces or tabs, in my test.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to "prepare" for splitting, just split by `\n`, optionally surrounded by spaces:

```js
text = `   How razorback-jumping 
   frogs 
can
 \t   level six \t
         \t piqued gymnasts!`         
         
console.log(text.trim().split(/[ \t]*\n[ \t]*/g))
```

Comment: For my question, you can remove the leading whitespace. (I might have revised the question after you answered)

Comment: Is there an expression to match all whitespace *except* newlines? Can't use `\s` cuz includes newlines.

Comment: see the definition of `\s` @ https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions/Character_Classes

Comment: Extra credit: How to put the pattern in a variable? This fails: `
const sRegExp = "/\n[ ]*[\t]*/g"; 
newStr = oldStr.replaceAll(sRegExp, "\n");`

Comment: `const sRegExp = /\n[ ]*[\t]*/g` (no quotes)

Comment: Thx for that! I just realized your answer *isn't* an `or`. It doesn't have to be, because of the "0 or more" conditions. Effectively, it's the same as an `or` conditional.

Comment: Your expression isn't exactly the requested logic, as i don't need to remove spaces/tabs before the newline, just before. Also, it would be awesome if you could include in your answer setting the expression to a variable. Thx!

Answer (score 1):

The square brackets should work, but the `*` (or `+`) modifier must be on the outside of it:

```
newStr = oldStr.replaceAll(/\n[ \t]+/g, "\n");
```

I chose `+` because it means "1 or more occurrences", it makes no sense to replace if there are 0 occurrences.

Demo:

```js
let text = `ABC
   DEF
   \t\tGHI
\t\tJKL
MNO`;
console.log(text.split("\n"));

text = text.replaceAll(/\n[ \t]+/g, "\n");
console.log(text.split("\n"))
```

Comment: I see what you mean about 0 occurrences. Question: Is regex faster if there are fewer matches?

Comment: Can any of my other attempts be made to work? Would any be more succinct or better performing?

Comment: I'd expect the single replacement to be (somewhat) faster than two separate ones, but it will take thousands or perhaps millions of lines to be noticeable. To be sure you'd have to benchmark it yourself, that is beyond the original question.

Comment: It was difficult to choose the best answer. Your is slightly more succinct, because you combine both conditions inside the square brackets as an OR with `1 or more`, which seems a better reg ex, instead of two separate bracketed expressions with `0 or more`. But the selected answer shows how to split with a reg ex, which is awesome. Thx!